# Notification works just first time Android

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-service, alarmmanager

I am trying to create a settings page where users can set the time of the notification.

i get the time using a Time picker in this way:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(Impostazioni.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

            ViewOra.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
            ora=selectedHour; minuti=selectedMinute;   
            setNotifiche(selectedHour,selectedMinute); //i call the method set notification 
        }
    }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
    mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
    mTimePicker.show();
    Intent notifiche = new Intent(Impostazioni.this , Notifiche.class);
```

this is the method setNotification where i create the alarm manager

```
public void setNotifiche(int h,int m) {

    int hour=h; int minute=m;
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this , Notifiche.class);     
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Impostazioni.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent);
}
```

Finally this is the service Notifiche.class where i putted the notifications:

```
public void onCreate() {   

    Toast.makeText(this, "Notifiche", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Impostazioni.class);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("Test").setContentText("Attempt n1").setContentIntent(pending);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

The code seems work, i mean when i lunch the app and set a specific time in the settings page in works, but if i try to set again nothing happens. Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

make two changes and check if it works:
In setNotifiche

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Impostazioni.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

In the service

```
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
```

Mark it correct if it works.

Answer (score 0):

It could have to do with your choice of ID as well. If a notification of your ID 0 exists already and another notification of ID 0 is created, a new notification sound will not play. You must first cancel the existing notification, or use a different ID. Consider:

```
int id = new Random().nextInt(1000);
notify(id, mBuilder.build());
```